# Passing a parameter from c:out tag to struts s:text tag

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, jstl

The project is based on Struts2

I am making a dynamic menu base using XML. This XML will be parsed and build the final menu.

**The XML is:**

```
<menus>
    <menu>
        <name>menu.level1.Home</name>
        <action>transfer-to-account-input</action>
        <namespace>transaction</namespace>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <name>menu.level1.Accounts</name>
        <action>accounts-summary</action>
        <namespace>account</namespace>
    </menu>
</menus>
```

I've used JSTL to parse the XML

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<x:forEach select="$docRoot/menus/menu" var="menuvar">
    <c:set var="menuName">
        <x:out select="$menuvar/name" />
    </c:set>    
    <c:out value="${menuName}"/>
    <s:text name="%{menuName}" />
    ..... // s:url shoul also be called
</x:forEach>
```

The problem is that the `c:out` tag shows correct value like `menu.level1.Home` I pass this parameter the `s:text` to get value from struts resource bundle. But it is not working.

So, the question is how to pass a parameter from `c:set` to `s:text`?

By the way, are there better solutions for making a menu from XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<s:property value="%{#attr.menuName}" />
```

Not sure about xml but you can build menu from [`sj:menu`](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/MenuTag) tag